# Electron: Check box not changing value?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I've created a browser window that uses a check box to open and close itself however, only the checkbox in its  `true` state is being detected and not in its `false` state.

Here is my code in the renderer.js:

```
const {width, height} = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
let close = document.querySelector('input[name=open_close]');
close.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  if (this.checked = true) {
  console.log("renderer");
 ipcRenderer.send('expClose',width, height);
  }

  if(this.checked = false) {
 ipcRenderer.send('expOpen',width - 500, height - 450);
  }
});
```

And here is my my main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('expClose', function(e,width, height) {
    console.log('closed'); 
      mainWindow.setPosition(width - 75, height - 450);
  });
  
  ipcMain.on('expOpen', function(e,width, height) {
   console.log("opened")
   mainWindow.setPosition(width, height);
      
  });
```

Also my HTML if needed:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="setbtn" checked="false" id="settings" class="btnset">
```

I assumed that the false state isn't being detected because opened isn't being logged.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your checkbox should be named "open_close", no?

Comment: @SydneyY I um ... pasted the wrong htm, i had them too similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `=` (*assignment*) instead of `===` (*comparison*)

Change `if (this.checked = true) {`  to `if (this.checked === true) {` 
and  `if(this.checked = false) {` to `if(this.checked === false) {`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with this code:

```
const {width, height} = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
let close = document.querySelector('input[name=open_close]');
close.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  console.log("renderer");
 ipcRenderer.send('expClose',width, height);

  if(document.querySelector('input[name=open_close]:checked') !==null ) {
 ipcRenderer.send('expOpen',width - 500, height - 450);
  }
});
```